# nginx proxypass with multiple locations

Tags: nginx, proxy, location

I try to setup nginx such that it proxies requests to multiple locations. E.g. `/location1` and `/location2` should both be proxied to `http://localhost:8080`. I just can't figure out how to configure this without using multiple location blocks. I already tried:

```
location /(location1|location2) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/
}
```

which will only give 404s. And I've also tried:

```
location ~ /(location1|location2) {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/
}
```

Which will thrown an error that regular expressions are not allowed with proxy pass.

Is it possible to configure this proxy without having to create multiple location blocks?

Comment: Is not a problem for the missing ';'?

Comment: Thats a good question.

Comment: You can try this configure `location ~ ^/location[12]$ { return 200 "$uri";}`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently is missing a slash and a ';'. Try this:

`location ~ (/location1|/location2) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without involving regular expressions? This looks like a trivial case of a set of locations where the nested directives should match for either -- hardly a use case for bringing out the big gun that is regex pattern matching, which invariably is an unnecessary overhead here. I mean, the pattern is almost a degenerate case.